# Set screenlock setting interactively

Tags: android, adb, android-4.4-kitkat, cts, dragonboard

I want to set the screenlock mode to None in KitKat so I can run CTS.

I'm using the DragonBoard APQ8074 for development from Intrinsyc, and they just released their BSP for Android KitKat 4.4.2. Trouble is, it's unstable and the Security menu in Settings crashes. So I can't use `adb shell` to `input keyevents 19, 20, 21, 22, 23` to navigate.

`adb shell settings` command seems like it should work for this, but it's not. I tried these commands against 4.2, 4.3 and 4.4, and they seem to assign the values, but they don't visually result in any changes.

```
shell@msm8974:/ $ settings get system lockscreen_disabled 
null
shell@msm8974:/ $ settings put system lockscreen_disabled true
shell@msm8974:/ $ settings get system lockscreen_disabled 
true

shell@msm8974:/ $ settings get system screen_brightness
102
shell@msm8974:/ $ settings put system screen_brightness 255
shell@msm8974:/ $ settings get system screen_brightness 
255
```

Now I dunno if lockscreen_disabled is what I want, here, but [Settings.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-4.4.2_r2/core/java/android/provider/Settings.java) doesn't seem to provide a call to any sort of `unlock_mode`, so I dunno what else to do. I don't want to write an app to do this, I just want to set screen lock mode to `None` so I can run CTS. If I need to modify source, then make & flash a new image, I'm willing to do that, but I don't know what to modify. Thanks for any guidance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Got it figured out.

**1. Update settings.db using adb shell**

```
shell@msm8974:/ $ su
shell@msm8974:/ # sqlite3 /data/data/com.android.providers.settings/databases/settings.db
sqlite3> update secure set value=1 where name='lockscreen.disabled';
sqlite3> .quit
```

**2. Move or delete locksettings files**

```
shell@msm8974:/ # mkdir /data/system/lock
shell@msm8974:/ # mv /data/system/locksettings* lock
```

`adb reboot` and good to go.

Answer (score 3):

If there is no sqlite installed on the device use the following

**1. Set Settings**

```
adb shell settings put secure lockscreen.disabled 1
```

**2. reboot to recovery**

```
adb reboot recovery
```

**3. remove locksettings db files**

```
adb shell rm /data/system/locksettings.db
adb shell rm /data/system/locksettings.db-shm
adb shell rm /data/system/locksettings.db-wal
```

Comment: This is also generally just a nicer solution even if you do have sqlite because it lets the system handle everything. Also, if you are rooted you don't have to reboot to recovery

Answer (score 0):

You should use `lockscreen.disabled` as the variable name in the setting command, and `secure` as the name space:

```
shell@msm8974:/ $ settings put secure lockscreen.disabled 1
```